# Loading image in Spring application

Tags: image, spring, itext

I have this kind of solution in my Spring application:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/PDF-RTF/AddingPNGimagetoPdfdocument.htm

Anyhow my problem is that my picture is in different folder like WEB-INF/layout/picture.gif.
I don't get it to work. Is there any disrictions, maybe?

Comment: Image imageRight = Image.getInstance("path"); not working

Answer (score 2):

Move your picture to the classpath as a resource, so then you can load it to iText easily. In order to do that you should copy the image file to the directory where the classes are, so the image is packed into the JAR or alternatively is in /WEB-INF/classes directory if this is JAva webapp (war).

Factory method of `com.lowagie.itext.Image` takes `java.net.URL` as argument, so you  do this:

```
URL imageUrl = getClass().getResource("/your/image/package/image.png");
Image image = Image.getInstance(imageUrl);
```

Comment: Does it have to be in jar file to be a resource?

Comment: How do you package you application? Is this jar or war or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you try to access the images from a web browser directly.

---

Images that can directly accessed by an browser have to be located outside of the WEB-INF directory.

For example in a maven project

```
-project/main/src
  -webapp
    -images  <- in the same parent directory like META-INF and WEB-INF
    -META-INF
    -WEB-INF
```

Comment: How about not Maven? How do I format the path? e.g ../layout? I'm using Windows

Comment: MJgirl: Anyway, it is the same for not Maven: put the images (better an images folder) in the same director where the META-INF and WEB-INF subfolders are located. (Maven is only relevant for the stucture above (project/main/src/webapp))